# Force IE compatibility mode off in IE using tags for browser mode

Tags: html, jsp, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am using html5 with angularJs  using follwoing tag

This results in Browser mode set to IE8 Compat, and Document mode set to IE8 Standards.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app"  ng-app="myApp">

 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

This results in Browser mode="IE8 Compat" and Document mode="IE8 Standards".

How can i force for the IE Document Mode=IE8 Standards too, so my stuff will start working

Comment: I think you may need `"IE=EmulateIE8"`, but I do wonder what you need it _for_. If your HTML worked in IE8, but it stopped working in IE9, you should upgrade your HTML, not apply kludges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `IE=edge`, it will force the browser to use the latest version it has (IE8 will act as IE8, not compatibility mode) and removes the button for compatibility mode. This will give the best results for AngularJS

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Also, if you are running the site locally, IE will pick up on that and force compatibility mode on.  You can change this setting in IE, go to Tools –> Compatibility ViewSettings -> Uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View".

[image]

Comment: I have tried "IE=edge" and "IE=EmulateIE8". But Issue is same it is still showing Browser mode="IE8 Compat" .

Comment: I added about the IE Settings, not sure if you are running off your local PC or if the URL is local-looking.

Comment: By setting this meta tag, you tell IE to use standards mode even if there are comments or an XML declaration above the DOCTYPE. You determine what version of Internet Explorer can best view the page, and then set the meta tags to define that version.
IE 7:<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
IE 8:<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
IE 9:<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
If a customer comes to a page with a view mode higher than it supports it will ignore the tag and render the page the the mode it would have without the tag.